# Angular bootstrap-switch-button loads too late

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

Since bootstrap 4 does not provide a switch button I decided to download the "bootstrap-switch-button"
(https://gitbrent.github.io/bootstrap-switch-button/) plugin.

I included it in my angular.json like so:

```
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/bootstrap-switch-button/css/bootstrap-switch-button.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap-switch-button/dist/bootstrap-switch-button.min.js"
            ]
```

Yet, when i visit the page that holds my 2 switch buttons (used for sort ascening and descending) the first time, the buttons look like normal checkboxes. Only after refreshing (F5) the page do they display correctly...

This is how I am building them in my html:

```
      <input type="checkbox"
             formControlName="optionFirst"
             data-onstyle="outline-warning"
             data-offstyle="outline-warning"
             data-toggle="switchbutton"
             checked data-onlabel="<img src='..\..\..\..\assets\icons\sort_decrease.png'></img>"
             data-offlabel="<img src='..\..\..\..\assets\icons\sort_incr.png'></img>"/>
```

Comment: you can create a switch button only with css, see e.g. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp

Comment: thanks for that! that way i can also set them to align easily!